# Is there a way to add comments to tasks or the task list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, tasks, task-list

I cannot find how to add comments to the project tasks.

For example, if we have "Task A" and we need to update the status, we would like to leave a comment for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default columns at `Tasks content type` do not have a `comments` column, meanwhile, it has a `Description` column that can be used as comments column to add more details about your task , and to show it you should click on `show more` as shown below :

[image]

Also,if you don't want to use `Description` column ,you can add `comments` column to your task list content type that should be shown within task item at edit form as the following:

- Open SharePoint Designer > Connect to your Site.
- Go to List ad Library > click on your task list  > below customization section click edit list columns.
- from the above ribbon click on add existing site column, search for comments column and add it > then save.

[image]

- Now, when you try to edit your task item, you will find comments field.

**[Update]**

If you can't use Sharepoint Designer , try to do the following steps

**If you need to apply comments column for all lists that have Task Content Type**

- Open SharePoint Site > Go to Site Settings.
- Below `Web Designer Galleries` > click on `Site content types` .
- Try to find the Task Content Type below `List Content Type` .
- Click on Task > Click on `add from existing site columns`.
- Find the Comments field and then Add.
- Check yes to update all previous lists that have task list content type.
- click OK.

**If you need to add comments column only for this list .**

- Go to your list > List Settings > Add from existing site columns .

[image]

Comment: Can I achieve this without SharePoint Designer? I am having difficulty downloading and installing SharePoint Designer on my machine.

Comment: I keep getting a pop up saying "The installation of this package failed."

Comment: Yes , you can , but please tell me are you need to apply this for all task lists or only this task list ?

Comment: For all and any future tasks.

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: Hi @NavBowman is this solved your issue :) ? if no please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification  , if yes please set it as an answer and upvote it as mentioned at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour :) thanks for appreciating my time